# Click event on hover over a button using react

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I'm making a swiper slide project using react. And when I hover over a button, I want it to change the swiper without clicking it.
Is there a way to do this using react.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imstead of calling onclick, call the onmouseover. That works fine

```
<element onmouseover="myScript">
```